# 1&1 domain name redirects to heroku hosting

Tags: node.js, heroku, dns, subdomain, hosting

I deployed my node js app properly on heroku and it's working fine with the heroku provided domain name.

Now, I'm trying to link it with my personal domain name. On the heroku website, in the settings section of my app hosted by heroku, I have setup the domain name to be `my-app.com` and my heroku dns is set to `my-app.com.herokudns.com`

In 1&1, I have registered a domain name `my-app.com` that I redirect to `www.my-app.com`

Still in 1&1, I have then created a sub-domain called `www.my-app.com`, in which I have set the DNS CNAME to `my-app.com.herokudns.com`

I saved everything but when I go to `www.my-app.com`, the url shows `www.my-app.com/defaultsite` in which the content shows a heroku generic page telling me `There's nothing here, yet. Build something amazing`.

Could anyone has a clue on what  may be missing to connect to my app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS changes [take time to propagate through the network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Record_caching). Very often you'll have to wait before seeing them take effect.

This can be somewhat mitigated by setting your records' [time to live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#DNS_records) (TTL). This value specifies an expiry time for your records after which cached values should be re-fetched from the authoritative server:

> Shorter TTLs can cause heavier loads on an authoritative nameserver, but can be useful when changing the address of critical services like Web servers or [MX records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record), and therefore are often lowered by the DNS administrator prior to a service being moved, in order to minimize disruptions.

Note that if you are planning to change a DNS record its TTL should be lowered far enough before the change is made that old values will already  have expired. For example, if the record you plan to change has a TTL of 86400 seconds (24 hours) you should decrease it at least 24 hours before modifying its value.